# Kids christian music from the 80's

Tags: music

When I was a little kid, I used to listen to these tapes at night as I fell asleep. They made a big impression on me. I can't for the life of me figure out what they were (my parents have no clue) or where/if I can get them on CD.

The one song I remember most clearly is one that began with two kids talking about "forgiving 7x7x7x7x7x7x7x7..." Then, the song had the lyrics, "Be kind, one to another. Open hearted, forgiving each other. For even as God for Jesus sake, has forgiven you." Another one had the kids playing "Eye Spy" or something like that (maybe while it was raining?) and by the end of the skit/piece one of the kids spies something that's "red and yellow and orange and blue and..." and one of the kids objects that that isn't possible, and then they talk about rainbows or something. These are all vague recollections from about 25 years ago, so, I know I'm not giving a whole lot to go off of here...

We always referred to it as "the Creek Bank Kids". I found a cd online called "[Down by the Creek Bank](http://www.agapelandmusic.com/catalog/item/1572202/1021976.htm)" but after contacting the publisher [Agapeland](http://www.agapelandmusic.com/Agapeland_christian_music_CD.html), they responded to my inquiry about this and said they didn't recognize it, so it isn't them...

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is a new [question type](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) for this site. [We are currently discussing if it will be considered on or off-topic.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/should-we-accept-help-me-find-this-thing-questions)

Comment: I don't know if you received a proper welcome, but here's one: Welcome to the site. We are happy that you decided to participate. I see you're no stranger to SE, but this particular SE site is quite different than the others and is difficult to grasp how the community here works. Fortunately, we have meta post for you. [Start with this one to quell your frustrations](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient), if you are feeling any, then move on to the others that are linked there, expecially the first two.

Comment: Right. Back in the early days of SE (when it was just SO) this kind of question was a-ok. Now I guess it's called something like "let's play the guessing game" and just gets closed because... reasons (which I whole-heartedly disagree with and resent SE for :P ). I won't blame you for just closing it. There's just no other place on the internet for this to actually go, so, I put it here, hoping against hope. ;)

Comment: [I think the community has decided this is alright.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3767/3961) Also, 5 days since my first close vote and it is still the only one. Hence, +1.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a song.

Comment: Yes this is accurate info. My children listened to most of these mentioned above. My daughter is teaching her children scripture songs she remembers that were done as the ABC’s. The first one is All have sinned... the second Believe in the Lord Jesus Christ... Anyone recall what album this was on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is "Psalty's sleepytime helpers". There are a bunch of volumes, but one of them have the "be kind one to another" song on it!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your answer! It would be improved if you could identify the specific volume, and perhaps an Amazon page. Even better if you could post the lyrics to the song in question (to verify that it's the one in the OP). I hope you stick around to answer more questions on the site.

Comment: I've just noticed that [the OP already identified the song](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/kids-christian-music-from-the-80s#comment120075_30828), and it is indeed the one you mention. It's always useful to have the answer posted in the answer section rather than just in the comments, so good on ya for doing that.

Answer (score 4):

I listened to a lot of this type of music as a kid.  These kids musical albums, featuring kids singing the songs and some sort of story that runs in between the songs, were very popular in the 80s.  Churches and Christian schools often performed these as stage productions with kids.

Some of the more notable producers of these Christian kids musicals include:

- [Agapeland](http://www.agapelandmusic.com/Agapeland_christian_music_CD.html), which you mentioned, was a big publisher of this format, featuring "Music Machine," "Bullfrogs and Butterflies," "Nathaniel the Grublet," and others.
- Dottie Rambo's "[Down By the Creek Bank](http://www.brentwoodbenson.com/product/viewproduct.do?itemid=75707139)" was extremely popular.
- Jimmy and Carol Owens wrote several musicals, most notably "[Ants'hillvania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ants%27hillvania)."
- Debbie Kerner and Ernie Rettino created [Psalty the Singing Songbook](http://www.psalty.com/) musicals, with titles "The Kids Praise Album!", "Kids Praise! 2," "Kids Praise! 3," etc.
- [Joyful Heart Music](https://joyfulheart.org/) is the home of Colby the Computer (who also had a TV series) and Nannybird.
- [Kathie Hill](http://www.kathiehillmusic.com/index.php?main_page=index) is also a prolific producer of kids musicals, notably "Back at the Creekbank" (a sequel to "Down By the Creek Bank"), "Fish Tales," and many others.

I don't recognize the "forgiving" song you mentioned, but I am almost positive that the "I-Spy" song and the rainbow song you mentioned are from Kathie Hill's "[Back at the Creekbank](http://www.kathiehillmusic.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1_13)," the songs being "Riddle Me, Riddle Me" and "It's a Rainbow."

Comment: YES!!!! This very well might be the one! I listened to all the samples and the specific song I am asking about isn't one of the samples, but, two of the samples were the other two you mentioned :D. I've written the publisher to ask if they recognize it and will update the answer here when I hear back. THANKS!!!

Comment: Here's the song I was looking for http://www.psalty.com/track/694944/4-be-kind-one-to-another?trackship_id=780102 but, for some reason I remembered it in the context of a "Back at the Creekbank" type dialog/song mixture. It doesn't come that on this CD...

Comment: And, here it is. This CD is the one I was remembering. It's an "episode" (a little drama/story) all about forgiveness and has the "Be Kind" song on it. http://www.psalty.com/album/207957/psalty-s-sleepytime-helper-episode-4-blooper-s-bloopers-download

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these will look familiar many of the childrens 80's groups are shown. though I don't see the Rap-Sures, Prism (the Christian childrens group), Stephen Wiley and there are probably many more. https://www.google.com/search?q=Antshillvania&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS571US571&oq=Antshillvania&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8